# How to write a test (of e.g. the .size() if an ArrayList that's been put into a HashSet that has a nested for each loop in it?

Tags: java, arraylist, junit5, hashset, playing-cards

I'm new to Java, on an apprenticeship, and struggling really.
I'm wanting to write a junit5 test for this:
(I should add, this project is not finished, I'm working my way through trying to create a game of Blackjack while learning along the way)

```
public Deck() {

    ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();
        //fill deck with cards
    for (Suit suit: Suit.values()) {
        for (Rank rank: Rank.values()){
            cards.add(new Card(rank,suit));
        };
    }
    HashSet<Card> deck = new HashSet<>(cards);;
```

now I can quite easily get the answer with:
  `System.out.println(deck.size());`
but that's cheating.

I can't quite figure out how to write a test for e.g.
`void thereAre52CardsInADeck(){ }`
without just putting the whole block of code in there.
That seems inefficient.

Can anyone help/offer advice?

EDIT:
I really am entirely new to this, and fairly new to coding full stop, so apologies. This is part of a learning exercise for me.

1 - by "System.out.println(deck.size())" cheating, I meant just having that at the end of my Deck() class (i.e. and not in a junit test class) is cheating because I'm wanting to unit test everything

2 - my suit class is:

```
public enum Suit {HEARTS, CLUBS, Diamonds, Spades}
```

my Rank class is

```
public enum Rank {
    ACE(1), DEUCE(2), THREE(3), FOUR(4), FIVE(5), SIX(6), SEVEN(7), EIGHT(8), NINE(9), TEN(10), JACK(10), QUEEN(10), KING(10);
    private final int rankValue;

    private Rank(int rankValue) {
        this.rankValue = rankValue;
    }

    public int getRankValue(){
    return rankValue;
    }
}
```

My card class is:

```
public class Card {
    private final Rank rank;
    private final Suit suit;
    public Card (Rank rank, Suit suit) {
        this.rank = rank;
        this.suit = suit;
    }
    public Rank getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    public Suit getSuit(){
        return suit;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return rank + " of " + suit;
    }

}
```

My main right now is:
public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Deck deck = new Deck();
}
```

}

I've ran the project and know I can get the correct amount running it with System.out.println(deck.size()), and if I remove the .size() I get my full list too, but I've not managed to work it out in a Junit test.

Comment: How is `deck.size()` cheating? Isn't that exactly the kind of functionality that you're trying to test? And copying the code block is not just inefficient, but pointless: if you do that, then you're testing the **test code** and not the code in the class under test (and there's no guarantee that neither of those gets changed). Something like `assertEquals(52, new Deck().size))` should be fine (or maybe swap the arguments, I always forget which one is the expected and not all assertion systems agree).

Comment: Please add some more code to complete at least this class and also maybe a method that uses it.

Comment: assuming you have a getter method for your Deck class, you can then call the get method to get the deck from your Deck class after instantiating it in your junit test. Then assert that there are 52 cards. But this requires you to have class variables, meaning that the `HashSet<Card> deck` variable declaration needs to be outside the constructor.

Comment: @JoachimSauer thanks for taking the time to comment. I meant just having System.out.println(deck.size()); in my normal Deck class is cheating in the sense it's not Junit testing. No issues with using deck().size in my test class except it just flags up "Method Call Expected" on Deck()

Comment: @Bobby2Kills when you say " I'm wanting to unit test everything", what do you mean? you want to test that every single card is there?

Comment: @Bentaye sorry that was probably misleading on my part. I basically mean the things I am "testing" e.g. by doing System.out.prints to see if they work... I'm trying to learn to use proper Junit tests instead.

I'll need to get used to test-driven development for my apprenticeship, so trying to get better at testing full stop.

Answer (score 1):

Your code shows a constructor that uses local variables. You cannot unit test those inside details of a method or constructor.

You should unit test expected outputs of methods or constructors or interactions with other objects methods. (The interaction testing is a bit "higher level" but only until you find out how to use Mockito or another library that handles most stuff on that for you.)

If you keep that code in the constructor as it is, you cannot unit test anything there, as it has no side effects - except if you have unexpected side effects in the `Suit.values()` and `Rank.values()` (both `enums` I guess?) or in the constructor of `Card`.

Even the heap should be the same before and after as all objects probably get garbage collected after calling that constructor.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time with this. I'm not too sure what you mean by 'heap' but I'll look into it. My grasp on this is pretty poor right now and this is a learning exercise for me.
Mockito is next on the list of things I need to learn, and something I will eventually want to implement. 
This is a learning exercise for me, hoping to be able to create a functional version of Blackjack. Once I have that working, I'll be trying to make other card games and hope to learn more as I go along.

I've updated my post with the rest of my code so far.

Comment: Heap is the part of the main memory that java uses to store objects. As opposed to the stack, where parameters of method calls are stored. (Parameters with objects are always just references to that object, so the actual object data is stored in the heap while the reference as parameter is stored in the stack.) The operator `new` allocates memory on the heap that is freed again, when (simplified) the garbage collector finds no further reference to that object.

Answer (score 0):

Tell me if this what you want? Or else I can modify if its not exactly what you asked for

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class DeckTest {

    @Test
    void thereAre52CardsInADeck() {
        Deck deck = new Deck();

        int deckSize = deck.getDeckSize();

        Assertions.assertEquals(52, deckSize, "The deck should contain 52 cards");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. 
My code has evolved since posting this, but creating the deck in the @BeforeEach and also the getCards() method saved my bacon. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need both `cards` and `deck` in your `Deck` class, just go with

```
public class Deck {

    private final Set<Card> cards;

    public Deck() {
        cards = new HashSet<>();
        for (Suit suit : Suit.values()) {
            for (Rank rank : Rank.values()) {
                cards.add(new Card(rank, suit));
            }
        }
    }

    public Set<Card> getCards() {
        return cards;
    }

}
```

Then what you need to do is create a test class, first declare the dependency on junit5, here is for maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
  <version>5.9.2</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

(See [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api/5.9.2) if you are using another dependency management tool)

Then write the test this way:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.*;

class DeckTest {

    private Deck deck;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        deck = new Deck();
    }

    @Test
    void deckHad52Cards() {
        assertEquals(52, deck.getCards().size());
    }

}
```

#### Additionally:

As your cards are stored in a `Set`, that will ensure that there are no duplicate cards, but that only work if you override the `equals` method in your `Card` class, so add the following bit of code in `Card`

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
        return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    Card card = (Card) o;
    return rank == card.rank && suit == card.suit;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(rank, suit);
}
```

and you can then test hat by creating a test class for `Card`, ie `CardTest` and have the 2 following tests in it:

```
@Test
void sameCardsShouldBeEqual() {
    assertEquals(new Card(Rank.ACE, Suit.CLUBS), new Card(Rank.ACE, Suit.CLUBS));
}

@Test
void differentCardsShouldNotBeEqual() {
    assertEquals(new Card(Rank.KING, Suit.CLUBS), new Card(Rank.ACE, Suit.CLUBS));
}
```

After all this, you have tested that you have 52 distinct cards in your deck.